# /beta MS Graph /sites/lists lastModifiedDateTime is wrong?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using MS Graph API /beta endpoint to figure out if the list has been updated/changed.

Used the following query first:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/xxxxx?$expand=lists(select=id, name, system, lastModifiedDateTime)
```

And did get the following date:

```
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:23:37Z",
```

But when going against the items and see the dates on the latest item with the following query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/xxxxx.sharepoint.com,92af4fbc-04bc-46d8-9c78-f63832fbf48a,1b59d85a-41bd-4498-a64c-17bd13069d90/lists/b9c39323-076a-4ae7-942b-1d0060a6b352/items

you can see the dates:

```
"createdDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:23:37Z"

"lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:29:14Z",
```

You can see that lastModifiedDateTime property on the list looks like actually `lastCreatedDateTime`?

Best Regards,
Kim

edit:

First graph request gets the SitePages list and its lastModifiedDateTime:

```
    {
        "id": "b9c39323-076a-4ae7-942b-1d0060a6b352",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:23:37Z",
        "name": "SitePages",
        "system": {}
    },
```

But if we then look at the items of the list, we can see that it has an item with a higher lastModifiedDateTime (second graph request):

```
        "createdDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:23:37Z",
        "eTag": "\"27e03a98-9321-4586-8ef1-0b5323c26730,6\"",
        "id": "8",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-08T10:29:14Z",
```

We can also see that the createdDateTime of the listitem is the same as the list lastModifiedDateTime. Looks like a bug in the api to mee. The date in the first request should be "2018-10-08T10:29:14Z". Dont you agree?

Answer (score 0):

As your description, I assume you want to know why the `LastModifyDateTime` is different.

Base on my test, your first link is to get the `lastModifyDateTime` of the special site,
but your second link is about the items of the `b9c39...`.

We can use the MS Graph Explore to check whether this two site has some differences.

Comment: Edited my question with more details now. Looks like a bug in the /beta endpoint. It seems like the LastModifiedDate of list is actually the date when the latest item was added, not updated.

Comment: If you have this problem on the [github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it appears to be a bug, for [`List` resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/list) `lastModifiedDateTime` property returns *invalid* value, it seems to be mapped to the *last list item date and time when the item was created* (`ListItem.createdDateTime`)

It could also be confirmed as a bug using the following endpoints (in both examples a *valid* `lastModifiedDateTime` value is returned):

- https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/drive/root?select=lastModifiedDateTime
- https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbyid({list-id})?$select=LastItemModifiedDate

Meanwhile as a workaround the following solution could be considered to enumerate site lists:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/drives?expand=root(select=lastModifiedDateTime)
```

where `root/lastModifiedDateTime` returns a valid value

> Limitation: Only returns document libraries

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Hope someone from MS Graph team reads this :)